# Suppose that the cyclic group $G$ acts on a set $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Suppose that the cyclic group $G$ acts on a set $S$ and $g_1$ and $g_2$ generate $G$. Show that $|$Fix $g_1|=|$Fix $g_2|$. We know that there is a function $\psi: G\times S\rightarrow S$ with the properties (if $\psi(g,s)$ is written as $g(s)$) that $(g^\star\cdot g^*)(s)=g^\star(g^*(s))$ and $e_G(s)=s~\forall g^\star,g^*\in G, s\in S$.

I am just looking for a hint to start with.

Comment: Does $\operatorname{Fix} g$ mean the points fixed by $g$?

Comment: Yes. Fix $g=\{s\in S|g(s)=s\}$

Comment: @Pixelwyrm: Is $G$ finite?

Comment: @BabakS. G is not necessarily finite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If $g$ generates $G$, then the elements fixed by $g$ under the action are exactly the elements fixed by $G$ under the action.

Comment: @Pixelwyrm: Fix $G$ is the set of all elements fixed by each member of $G$: $\{s\in S\mid g(s)=s\;\forall g\in G\}$.

Comment: Suppose that $G$ fixes an element $s$.  Then since $g\in G$, it follows that $g$ also fixes $s$.  This shows that Fix $G\subset$ Fix $g$.  Now, suppose that $g$ fixes $s$.  What does $g^n$ do to $s$ for any integer $n$?  The answer to this question should show that Fix $g\subset $ Fix $G$, so that the two sets are equal.